# org.hibernate.validator.InvalidValue in hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, seam2

I am trying to migrate my application from hibernate 3 to 4 also I am using Seam 2.2 and I am getting the compilation error `The type org.hibernate.validator.InvalidValue cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`.

Somehow the `StatusMessages.instance().add` is indirectly referencing hibernate.

```
if(this.acctNum==null || this.acctNum.trim().length()==0) {
    StatusMessages.instance().add(StatusMessage.Severity.ERROR, " Please enter an account number");
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the issue by adding the following dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator-legacy</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.2.GA</version> 
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```